# How get the current language setting on Android

Tags: android

I want to change the view of my TimePicker to 24h, if a user of Germany is watching it.

So I want to have a code like this:

```
if(language-setting = Germany)
    tp.setIs24HourView(true);
else
    tp.setIs24HourView(false);
```

I think it should somehow work with "locale", but I can not figure it out.

Comment: why don't you use settings preferences about clock? The user then defines if it's 24h or 12h.

Comment: @Netelnstein: I dont want to add an additional preference. I think it is no good usability :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the current default

```
Locale.getDefault();
```

Based on this you can compare.

Comment: @PravionCG: ok it is working:  if(Locale.getDefault().equals(Locale.GERMANY))
   tp.setIs24HourView(true);

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
String language=Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    Log.d("lang", "langg"+language);
    if(language.equals("en")){
        Log.d("lang_english", "langg"+language);
        //send_msg_text.
    }
    if(language.equals("ar")){
        Log.d("lang_arabic", "langg"+language);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be respecting the user setting, which you can get from [DateFormat.is24HourFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat%28android.content.Context%29).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```